# How to extract correct value in multiple array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this result and I want to extract some information like service-name,
price, expected-delivery-date ...
How to do the loop and extract these informations correctly.

Thanks

```
    Array
(
    [price-quotes] => Array
        (
            [price-quote] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [service-code] => DOM.EP
                            [service-link] => Array
                                (
                                    [@value] => 
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => service
                                            [href] => https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/service/DOM.EP?country=CA
                                            [media-type] => application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml
                                        )

                                )

                            [service-name] => Expedited Parcel
                            [price-details] => Array
                                (
                                    [base] => 8.20
                                    [taxes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [gst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 0.41
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 5
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [pst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 0.82
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 9.975
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [hst] => 0
                                        )

                                    [due] => 9.42
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                            [option] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [option-code] => DC
                                                    [option-name] => Delivery confirmation
                                                    [option-price] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [adjustments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [adjustment] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => FUELSC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => Fuel surcharge
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => 0.24
                                                            [qualifier] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [percent] => 3
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => V1DISC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => SMB Savings
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => -0.25
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [weight-details] => 
                            [service-standard] => Array
                                (
                                    [am-delivery] => 
                                    [guaranteed-delivery] => 1
                                    [expected-transit-time] => 1
                                    [expected-delivery-date] => 1983
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [service-code] => DOM.PC
                            [service-link] => Array
                                (
                                    [@value] => 
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => service
                                            [href] => https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/service/DOM.PC?country=CA
                                            [media-type] => application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml
                                        )

                                )

                            [service-name] => Priority
                            [price-details] => Array
                                (
                                    [base] => 16.86
                                    [taxes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [gst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 0.88
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 5
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [pst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 1.76
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 9.975
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [hst] => 0
                                        )

                                    [due] => 20.3
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                            [option] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [option-code] => DC
                                                    [option-name] => Delivery confirmation
                                                    [option-price] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [adjustments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [adjustment] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => FUELSC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => Fuel surcharge
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => 1.31
                                                            [qualifier] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [percent] => 8
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => V1DISC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => SMB Savings
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => -0.51
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [weight-details] => 
                            [service-standard] => Array
                                (
                                    [am-delivery] => 
                                    [guaranteed-delivery] => 1
                                    [expected-transit-time] => 1
                                    [expected-delivery-date] => 1983
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [service-code] => DOM.RP
                            [service-link] => Array
                                (
                                    [@value] => 
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => service
                                            [href] => https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/service/DOM.RP?country=CA
                                            [media-type] => application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml
                                        )

                                )

                            [service-name] => Regular Parcel
                            [price-details] => Array
                                (
                                    [base] => 8.2
                                    [taxes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [gst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 0.41
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 5
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [pst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 0.82
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 9.975
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [hst] => 0
                                        )

                                    [due] => 9.42
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                            [option] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [option-code] => DC
                                                    [option-name] => Delivery confirmation
                                                    [option-price] => 0
                                                    [qualifier] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [included] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [adjustments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [adjustment] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => FUELSC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => Fuel surcharge
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => 0.24
                                                            [qualifier] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [percent] => 3
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => V1DISC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => SMB Savings
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => -0.25
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [weight-details] => 
                            [service-standard] => Array
                                (
                                    [am-delivery] => 
                                    [guaranteed-delivery] => 
                                    [expected-transit-time] => 2
                                    [expected-delivery-date] => 1982
                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [service-code] => DOM.XP
                            [service-link] => Array
                                (
                                    [@value] => 
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [rel] => service
                                            [href] => https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/service/DOM.XP?country=CA
                                            [media-type] => application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml
                                        )

                                )

                            [service-name] => Xpresspost
                            [price-details] => Array
                                (
                                    [base] => 9.96
                                    [taxes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [gst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 0.52
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 5
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [pst] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [@value] => 1.04
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [percent] => 9.975
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [hst] => 0
                                        )

                                    [due] => 11.99
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                            [option] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [option-code] => DC
                                                    [option-name] => Delivery confirmation
                                                    [option-price] => 0
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [adjustments] => Array
                                        (
                                            [adjustment] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => FUELSC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => Fuel surcharge
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => 0.77
                                                            [qualifier] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [percent] => 8
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [adjustment-code] => V1DISC
                                                            [adjustment-name] => SMB Savings
                                                            [adjustment-cost] => -0.3
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [weight-details] => 
                            [service-standard] => Array
                                (
                                    [am-delivery] => 
                                    [guaranteed-delivery] => 1
                                    [expected-transit-time] => 1
                                    [expected-delivery-date] => 1983
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

example to extract code
 $preserve_keys: (0=>never, 1=>strings, 2=>always)

```
  function array_flatten($array, $preserve_keys = 1, &$newArray = Array()) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $child) {
      if (is_array($child)) {
        $newArray =& array_flatten($child, $preserve_keys, $newArray);
      } elseif ($preserve_keys + is_string($key) > 1) {
        $newArray[$key] = $child;
      } else {
        $newArray[] = $child;
      }
    }
    return $newArray;
  }


  print_r( '<br>' );
  $test = array_flatten($result, 1);
  echo $test;
```

Comment: I'd look at Recursive Array Iterators - http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: I found this function but I don't know if it's the best to extract each value. For example there is 4 'service-code' and I need to search in each 'service-name' or price the different values and to display it (see above)

Comment: Please specify your need. As I see it this array is well organised. What exactly do you need to get from it? Please provide the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to loop price-quote.

```
  foreach($array['price-quotes']['price-quote'] as $key=>$value){
      echo '<br/>service-name : '.$value['service-code'];
      echo '<br/>price : '.$value['price-details']['due'];
      echo '<br/>expected-delivery-date : '.$value['service-standard']['expected-delivery-date'];
      echo "<hr/>";
      // or you can create an array
      $new_array[$key]['service-name'] = $value['service-code'];
      $new_array[$key]['price'] = $value['price-details']['due'];
      $new_array[$key]['expected-delivery-date'] = $value['service-standard']['expected-delivery-date'];
  }
```

Output :

```
service-name : DOM.EP
price : 9.42
expected-delivery-date : 1983
===============
service-name : DOM.PC
price : 20.3
expected-delivery-date : 1983
===============
service-name : DOM.RP
price : 9.42
expected-delivery-date : 1982
===============
service-name : DOM.XP
price : 11.99
expected-delivery-date : 1983
===============
```